# Is it possible to convert an L1 VPC (CfnVpc) to an L2 Vpc (IVpc)

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

Due to severe limitations of the `Vpc` construct, we've had to change our code to use `CfnVpc` so not to have to destroy the VPC when we add or remove subnets.

This has proven to be very problematic...

The primary issue is that a lot of constructs expect an `IVpc` when creating them `BastionHostLinux` is an example.

> error TS2322: Type 'CfnVPC' is not assignable to type 'Vpc | IVpc'

When using the `CfnVpc`, I need to do this is a separate stack and them import it using a loopup in the new stack. This isn't a problem moving forward but all legacy deployments cannot be updated to work with the new code (100's of them).

I am currently trying to figure out a way to get the `CfnVpc` to convert to an `IVpc` but this has been a bit of a problem for me.

There is a ticket on GitHub already for this: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14809

Skinny85 responded that this is how you could accomplish this:

```js
const cfnInclude = new cfn_inc.CfnInclude(this, 'VpcTemplate’,
    templateFile: ‘vpc-template.yaml',
});

const cfnVpc = cfnInclude.getResource('VPC') as ec2.CfnVPC;
const privateSubnet1 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateSubnet1') as ec2.CfnSubnet;
const privateSubnet2 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateSubnet2') as ec2.CfnSubnet;
const cfnRouteTable1 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateRouteTable1') as ec2.CfnRouteTable;
const cfnRouteTable2 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateRouteTable2') as ec2.CfnRouteTable;

const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, ‘ImportedVpc', {
    vpcId: cfnVpc.ref,
    availabilityZones: cdk.Fn.getAzs(),
    privateSubnetIds: [privateSubnetl.ref, privateSubnet2.ref],
    privateSubnetRouteTableIds: [cfnRouteTablel.ref, cfnRouteTable2.ref],
});
```

The issue with this is that he is importing an CloudFormation template file.

I asked him about this but he responded:

> It shouldn't matter where the CfnVPC is coming from - the same principle applies.

Ok, so he's saying it is possible but didn't clarify how:

```js
const privateSubnet1 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateSubnet1') as ec2.CfnSubnet;
const privateSubnet2 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateSubnet2') as ec2.CfnSubnet;
const cfnRouteTable1 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateRouteTable1') as ec2.CfnRouteTable;
const cfnRouteTable2 = cfnInclude.getResource('PrivateRouteTable2') as ec2.CfnRouteTable;
```

Can be done with `CfnVpc`.

I have tried looking into using the `node` from my `CfnVpc` and I can see some of the data necessary like subnets but I am unable to get it to work with Typescript.

e.g. `this.vpc.node.scope?.publicSubnets` is just giving me an error saying `publicSubnets` are not part of `IConstruct`.

I haven't messed with Typescript for a year so I am a little rusty. I am not able to even get that to work.

Has anyone been able to get this to work? Am I missing something really simple that I am overlooking?

Any assistance on this is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The VPC should not be recreated when you add or remove subnets - are you supplying the `cidrMask` prop in `SubnetConfiguration`?

Comment: I've run into many issues with the Vpc being replaced when making changes to the subnets and/or route tables where it will replace a Vpc with deployed systems. For this reason, we moved towards CfnVpc. I can't find the issue for this currently but I wasn't the only one experiencing this.

Comment: It was probably caused by improper use of the construct such as allowing the default behavior of even CIDR distribution.

Comment: I think you are right on this. They were originally created with the default VPC and we just defined the subnets with the cidr on the VPC. Not on the subnets. So when we added new subnets, years later, it was destructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CfnVpc` does not create any subnets - those are created with `CfnSubnet`. So you don't have to use `cfnInclude`, just use the `CfnSubnet` objects you created.

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something simple... just can't believe I missed something so obvious...